# Forecasting shows a massive gap in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, agile

I'm having really odd problems with my VSTS Forecasting tool - It doesn't seem to matter what I set the Forecast velocity to, it leaves a massive gap of around 20 stories before it starts doing anything. Has anyone else had an issue like this and can point me at what may be causing a problem?

I'm sorry there's not much more to go on but I can't offer much more without providing my product backlog and I can't do that.

I've tried changing the settings to only show Backlog Item level and below.

Here's a screen grab - I've had to do it in 2 parts because I actually have to scroll down to see any of the forecast lines...

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Moving the items with no estimation value to the bottom of the backlog made no difference either (although I would expect a fair few more break lines before hitting that point)

Comment: Are those stories by any chance linked to the current sprint or a past sprint? Can you post a screenshot of what you;re seeing?

Comment: No they aren't - I might be able to hide the titles

Comment: That looks really weird! I suggest submitting a feedback item over at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: Replicated at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/23581/forecasting-shows-a-massive-gap-in-visual-studio-t.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that (in most cases) I was using the 'Story Points' rather than the 'Effort' field (because that's what they are!). I fixed the issue by replicating all of my story points data into the 'Effort' field. The Story Pints field doesn't actually seem to do very much.

This article: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow seems to disagree with this theory however.

Comment: In that case, are you know the agile or in the scrum template? What is your main backlog workitem name? User story or product backlog item?

Comment: Ahhh, yes, you're using the scrum template judging from the 'new work item box'. The scrum template uses a more generic field called 'effort' because scrum doesn't dictate what kind of estimation method you should use. The Agile, originally MSF Agile template uses a fixed estimation method and hence uses the exact name. It can be confusing when both types of project are active on the same account, as both types of fields show up.

Comment: You would think that sticking to one name or at least making them aliases for the same data would make sense but never mind.

Comment: I know - The annoying 'you can accept this answer tomorrow' set up means I don't end up doing it until next time I'm on SO